# \foreach and \def problems

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I've been trying to make a tikzpicture in 3d, using tikz-3dplot, that consists of a set of nested circular cones around the \pm z axis.

There is one parameter that should control the whole thing, with the \pm z coordinate, the cone angle and the length of the side all dependent on this parameter.

I am trying to get a general diagram where I input the parameter and that’s it.

I have been trying to use \foreach to do this and am getting nowhere - I’m not an intuitive coder - which is v frustrating.

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

An example of what I want to do (made in POVRay with the lengths and angles hard wired in) is

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def \l {1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\L}{sqrt(\l*(\l+1))}
   \begin{axis}[view={45}{45},
                axis lines=center,
                axis on top,
                xlabel=$x$,
                ylabel=$y$,
                zlabel=$z$,
                no marks,
            xmin=-\l-1, xmax=\l+1,
            ymin=-\l-1, ymax=\l+1,
            zmin=-\l-1, zmax=\l+1,
]
\foreach \m in {-\l,...,\l}
     \addplot3 [no markers,samples=51, domain=0:2*pi,variable=\t]
                                      ({\L*(acos(\m/\L))*cos(\t r)},{\L*(acos(\m/\L)*sin(\t r)},\m);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you put an [mwe](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing what you have done?

Comment: Hi muzimuzhi - I'm not even close yet - in the fog of frustration. The part that I can't work out is how to nest the values properly given a \def of \l, which is the single parameter. the parameters are \l : an integer > 1, \m - from integers in the range -\l to + \l and forms the z coordinate, the length of the side sqrt(\l*(\l+1)) and the cone angle acos(\m/(sqrt(\l*(\l+1)))). Using arc, the start -> stop angle should be 2* acos(\m/(sqrt(\l*(\l+1)))) and yet when I try to define the angle, say \T, my code falls over completely

Comment: "when I try to define the angle, say \T, my code falls over completely". Maybe you can start with providing the example "falling with \T".

Comment: Hi muzinuzhi - I have this at the moment; it doesn't crash but equally it doesn't plot any of the circles; I thought I'd try and get the circles first and worry about the cones later. How do I add the code for the mwe?

Comment: You can directly edit the question, and paste your code in "code sample" (just press the button showing a pair of braces).

Comment: Multiple remarks here: `pgfplots` works by default with angles in degrees, so you should use the axis option `trig format=rad` if you want to stick with radians. Also, put braces around the second argument of `\foreach` for the sake of readability and reliability of the code. Moreover, when you debug code, do not fix axis limits, it may hide erroneous yet informative output. Finally for such complex 3d plots, `asymptote` is probably better suited  than `tikz`

Comment: @BamboOo think you so much for taking a look. It fails in rads or degrees. I appreciate your comments - I’ve not ever used asymptote. The physics is trivial and this should be simple - it’s just the shape of quantum angular momentum. I’m almost blind w/ frustration so I really appreciate your help